# Unable to run F# nunit tests with Resharper after upgrade to VS2012

Tags: f#, nunit, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm trying to upgrade our solution from V2012 to V2012 targeting 4.5. We have some F# code with unit tests, which is written using NUnit. We are using Resharper to execute our tests in Visual Studio.

After upgrading projects to VS2012 our F# unit tests does not show in Resharpers Unit Tests windows.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [What's New in ReSharper 7](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#unit-testing) page says that ReSharper 7 introduced NUnit 2.6 as the default version for unit testing.

According to the [NUnit Release Notes](http://nunit.org/?p=releaseNotes&r=2.6.2), support for VS2012 / .NET 4.5 was introduced in NUnit 2.6.2.

If ReSharper 7 is using NUnit 2.6 (Final Release), that's probably why it's not picking up on your unit tests after upgrading your projects. I think your best bet is to contact [ReSharper Support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/) or the [ReSharper Developer Community](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper) and ask if there's a way to get things working; if not, they should be able to put NUnit 2.6.2 into the next release (ReSharper 7.1).

Comment: If this is the problem then you can tell ReSharper to used an installed version of NUnit rather than the built in version. Go to Tools -> Unit Testing -> NUnit in the ReSharper settings and have a look at the 'Specified NUnit installation' under 'Run tests with'.

Comment: That isn't the problem. I can easily run C# NUnit tests and I can also run F# unit tests using nunit-console.

Comment: I have also tried upgrading to NUnit 2.6.2 and have Resharper point to that installation without any luck

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when trying to use the ReSharper keyboard shortcut to run my tests or when I right click inside the class/method or on the test file, but it works when I right click the .sln and select Run tests.

Hope that helps others as well!